# PHP - Replace all {strings} from variable

Tags: php, str-replace

I have this variable:

```
$content = "Hello {file1}. Welcome to {file2}. Status: {file3}";
```

I want to replace all `{strings}` with different include files.

For example

```
{file1} = file1.php
{file2} = file2.php
{file3} = file3.php
```

So the final output of $content to include those files as well.

How can i do it?

Comment: Just use variables and put the variables in the string?

Comment: Just going off topic here but if that actually is your variable, I assume your strings are very short and I dont think it's the best thing to store the small strings in different files.

Comment: I forgot to mention I am using CKEditor and it comments out php that's why I thought of adding {strings} and then maybe with str_replace to replace them with include files?

Comment: That is a pretty important piece of information that you have ommited and changes everything. Now none of this makes sense.

Comment: Do you want the file name to be there or the contents of the file name??

Comment: the contents of the filename

Comment: And what are in each file? PHP code? You have given them .php? So do you want to include the PHP code? We are not psychic give us more details!

Comment: Ok sorry for my feedback.

Comment: Inside the php files it has php code yes which i want to show on the place of those strings.

Comment: I think you need to rethink your string/data structure. And also there is still not enough information. Do the .php files output something? In the example given it doesn't make sense to include php code at the given spots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to identify the placeholders and replace them with something else:

```
$content = "Hello {file1}. Welcome to {file2}. Status: {file3}";
$replacements = array(
    '{file1}' => 'file1.php',
    '{file2}' => 'file2.php',
    '{file3}' => 'file3.php',
);

$output = preg_replace_callback(
    '/\{.*?\}/',
    function (array $matches) use ($replacements) {
        $item = $matches[0];
        if (isset($replacements[$item])) {
            // simple replacement: replace the key in $replacements with the value
            $item = $replacements[$item];
        }
        return $item;
    },
    $content
);
```

The code above produces the string `"Hello file1.php. Welcome to file2.php. Status: file3.php"` which is not what you want but it shows you the way to go.

If you want to put the raw content of file `file1.php` instead of `{file1}` a.s.o. then use function [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to get it:

```
        if (isset($replacements[$item])) {
            // replace with the raw content of the file
            $item = file_get_contents($item);
        }
```

If you want to [`include 'file1.php'`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) then you need to write a small function to include the file and capture the output it might produce:

```
        if (isset($replacements[$item])) {
            // replace with the content produced by the included file
            $item = includeFile($item);
        }

// ... somewhere after the rest of the code...
function includeFile($file)
{
    ob_start();
    include($file);
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here your starting delimeter should be "{" and ending delimeter "}" and the parameters are your file name variables collected in an array.

```
while (true) {
            //Find starting delimiter
            $paramStart = strpos($this->_templateText, $this->_delimiters[0], $index);

            //No more starting delimiters. Copy rest of the message and return
            if ($paramStart === false) {
                $message .= substr($this->_templateText, $index);
                break;
            }

            //Copy portion up to the starting delimiter to message
            $message .= substr($this->_templateText, $index, $paramStart-$index);

            //Find ending delimiter
            $paramEnd = strpos($this->_templateText, $this->_delimiters[1], $paramStart + $startDelimiterLength);

            //No matching ending delimiter
            if ($paramEnd === false) {
                break;
            }

            //Get the portion between delimiters (i.e. parameter name)
            $paramName = substr(
                $this->_templateText,
                $paramStart + $startDelimiterLength,
                $paramEnd - ($paramStart + $startDelimiterLength)
            );

            //Insert parameter into message
            if (isset($parameters[$paramName])) {
                $message .= $parameters[$paramName];
            }

            //Continue from where we left off
            $index = $paramEnd + $endDelimiterLength;
        }
```